# Wordpress programming

Tags: wordpress, css, wordpress-theming

Dear stackoverflow friends,

I have a little problem with my wordpress website what I am making. I need a .gif file under my header with no space between. How can i fix that?

[image]

so you can now see the image this is what i mean
Kind regards,

Murtaza

Comment: you did not include any code or a link. there is no way anyone will be able to help you

Comment: I am working in my localhost and i can't upload an image I need 10 reputation

Comment: Aryeh Armon I have upload an image

Comment: Its related to **CSS**, please edit your question and add CSS tag in it, and no one can help you with this image.